# A condition under which sidelengths of a triangle are in HP

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

If D , E , F are points of contact of the inscribed circle with sides BC , CA , AB of a triangle , show that if the squares of AD , BE , CF are in arithmetic progression, then the sides of the triangle are in harmonic progression
I found this question in SL Loney - Plane Trigonmetry

Comment: And what did you do? I can guide if you show me your effort.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Answer (score 2):

By the given and by law of cosines we have
$$AD^2+CF^2=2BE^2$$ or
$$c^2+\frac{(a+c-b)^2}{4}-\frac{(a+c-b)(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{2a}+$$
$$+a^2+\frac{(a+c-b)^2}{4}-\frac{(a+c-b)(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{2c}=$$
$$=2\left(c^2+\frac{(b+c-a)^2}{4}-\frac{(b+c-a)(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{2b}\right)$$ or
$$(2ac-ab-bc)\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c-a)=0$$ or
$$ab+bc=2ac$$ or
$$\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}{2}=\frac{1}{b}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the touching points joined to their opposite points concur at the Gergonne point. (But we do not need this).

[image]

It is easy to show $DC=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$ and after a little trigonometry and algebra we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2= \frac{(-a+b+c)(a^2+a(b+c)-2(b-c)^2)}{4a} \\
y^2= \frac{(a-b+c)(b^2+b(a+c)-2(a-c)^2)}{4b} \\
z^2= \frac{(a+b-c)(c^2+c(b+a)-2(b-a)^2)}{4c} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now for these to be in Arithmetic progression we require that the sum of two of them equals $2$ times the third ... lets see what reduce makes of this ?

[image]

So we have $2ab-bc-ca=0$ , in other words the sides are in harmonic progression. (Note that the other bracket cannot be zero).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to provide your text a cleaner figure. But I didn't want to erase myself the previous figure : up to you to agree or not...

Comment: @JeanMarie That is brilliant. Can you tell me what software you use to draw figures like this ? Your figure also makes it clear that the Gergonne point & the incenter are different points. Thank you $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I have used Geogebra.